# Forcing user to select one of the checkboxes in dialog box before proceeding with installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation, conditional-statements

using vs2010 installer, I have added a dialog box with two checkboxes, I want the "Next"button to be active only if either of the check boxes are selected. is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, as in the case with common radio button pattern where you have to select “I agree” to move to the next screen. You can try to implement something similar. Yet you may need to introduce some custom actions because MSI does not re-evaluate control conditions right away.

The simplest solution would be to check whether one of them or both are checked when user clicks Next. In general your UI should have the most common defaults and should allow users to click through the installer.